# Fatal error: Call to undefined function availableDate()

Tags: php, sql

I get this error when trying to run this, what do it mean?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $partySize = $_POST['partysize'];
        $catering = $_POST['catering'];

        print_r($date);
        print_r($partySize);
        print_r($catering);

        include "/diska/www/include/coa123-13-connect.php";
        $host='co-project.lboro.ac.uk';
        $dbName='coa123wdb';

        $dsn = "mysql://$username1:$password1@$host/$dbName"; //Data Source Name

        require_once('MDB2.php'); //Just include this line into your program - you do not have to have the source in your directory
        $db =& MDB2::connect($dsn); //Try to make a connection

        if (PEAR::isError($db)) {
            die($db->getMessage());
        }

        //step 1 - query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM venue
        WHERE capacity >= $partySize";

        //step 2 - executing the query
        $result =& $db->query($sql);
        if (PEAR::isError($sql)) {
            die($result->getMessage());
        }

        $valueIDArray = array();

        while($row = $result -> fetchrow()){
            $valueIDArray[] = $row[0];
        }


        $values = implode(',', $valueIDArray);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM venue_booking
        WHERE venue_id IN ($values)";

        //step 2 - executing the query
        $result1 =& $db->query($query);
        if (PEAR::isError($query)) {
            die($result1->getMessage());
        }

        while($row = $result1 -> fetchrow()){
            $idValue[] = $row[0];
            $dateValues[] = $row[1];
        }

        availableDate($dateValues,$date,$idValue, $db); //Line error points to

        function availableDate($bookedDates, $date, $idValue, $db){
```

I have commeted on the line the error points to, this file works when its in its own PHP file but when inside the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) statement it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Move the function definition outside the `if` statement. There's almost never a good reason to do that -- the only excuse might be if you wanted different definitions of the function depending on a condition, but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing. If you define a function inside an `if`, you have to define it before you call it; functions defined at top-level can be called from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

call `availableDate` after it's defined, if you already have to define it inside of `if` statement.

Ex.

```
function availableDate($bookedDates, $date, $idValue, $db){
...
}

//and then call it...    
availableDate($dateValues,$date,$idValue, $db); //Line error points to
```

EDIT:

Example of non-working function defined inside of conditional statement

```
if(1){

    func('a');

    function func($a){
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

This wont work, but this will:

```
if(1){

    function func($a){
        echo $a;
    }

    func('a');            
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't matter. It's PHP

Comment: @asprin Try for yourself, it does matter

Comment: That's new. Let me try it.

Comment: @asprin It does matter for conditionally declared functions (i.e. inside an `if`).

Comment: I'm confused here. Conditionally declared functions? Here is fiddle to help you out with the explanation http://codepad.viper-7.com/v69JCE

Comment: @deceze Nice explanation, I'm not so good with words so I edited my answer with an example.